# Date issue convert in sql

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a date field I.[Creation Date Key]. I am going to display this field in 3 ways. One in its original format of yyyy-mm-dd tt:tt:tt

I am also going to display it as YYYYMM by using the following:

```
CONCAT (YEAR(I.[Creation Date Key]) , SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(6),(I.[Creation Date Key]), 112),5,2))
```

Output is YYYYMM

Is there any way I can display this as YYYYWW, with the following WW being the week of the year that it is? Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
year(I.[Creation Date Key]) * 100 + datepart(week, I.[Creation Date Key])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(06), @Date, 112) * 100 + DATEPART(WEEK, @Date)
```